# Should there be article in: "to cover postage"?

Tags: articles

> I hope Paypal added the correct amount of money to cover **(the)** postage to France.

I think that without (the) it would be better but the postage is used for a specific thing  (it is not used in general) it is for a book I mentioned before. So "the" might be necessary.

Answer (score 1):

I would certainly use *the* there, probably for the reason you give.

But it is possible to omit it.

Comment: Why is it possible to omit it ? Is it because postage is an  uncountable noun as money)

Comment: @user5577 - simply put, native speakers often omit articles and other small parts of speech where they are not necessary for the meaning. I gave my son the money for lunch; I gave my son money for lunch.